# Handling a subprocess' output in background threads and accepting user-provided sinks for the output

Tags: multithreading, rust, api

I have a [PR](https://github.com/dimo414/bkt/pull/43) swapping from `Command::output()` to a custom implementation using threads to handle the subprocess' stdout/stderr while the program is running, instead of waiting for it to complete. The approach was motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862682/113632).

```
// Executes the given command, capturing its output and exit code in the returned Invocation.
// If output_streams is present the output of the command is _also_ written to these streams
// concurrently, in order to support displaying a command's output while simultaneously caching
// it (instead of waiting for the command to complete before outputting anything).
fn execute_subprocess(
    cmd: impl Into<std::process::Command>,
    output_streams: Option<(impl Write+Send, impl Write+Send)>
) -> Result<Invocation> {
    fn maybe_tee(mut source: impl Read, mut sink: Option<impl Write>) -> std::io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        let mut ret = Vec::new();

        // This initialization can be avoided (safely) once
        // https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78485 is stable.
        let mut buf = [0u8; 1024 * 10];
        loop {
            let num_read = source.read(&mut buf)?;
            if num_read == 0 {
                break;
            }

            let buf = &buf[..num_read];
            if let Some(ref mut sink) = sink {
                sink.write_all(buf)?;
                sink.flush()?;
            }
            ret.extend(buf);
        }
        Ok(ret)
    }

    let (out_sink, err_sink) = match output_streams {
        Some((out, err)) => (Some(out), Some(err)),
        None => (None, None),
    };

    let mut command: std::process::Command = cmd.into();
    use std::process::Stdio;
    let command = command.stdout(Stdio::piped()).stderr(Stdio::piped());

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut child = command.spawn().with_context(|| format!("Failed to run command: {:?}", command))?;

    let child_out = child.stdout.take().ok_or(anyhow!("cannot attach to child stdout"))?;
    let child_err = child.stderr.take().ok_or(anyhow!("cannot attach to child stderr"))?;

    // Using scoped threads means we can take a Write+Send instead of a W+S+'static, allowing
    // callers to pass mutable references (such as `&mut Vec<u8>`). See also
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/113632
    let (stdout, stderr) = std::thread::scope(|s| {
        let thread_out = s.spawn(|| maybe_tee(child_out, out_sink));
        let thread_err = s.spawn(|| maybe_tee(child_err, err_sink));
        let stdout = thread_out.join().expect("child stdout thread failed to join").context("stdout pipe failed")?;
        let stderr = thread_err.join().expect("child stderr thread failed to join").context("stderr pipe failed")?;
        anyhow::Ok((stdout, stderr))
    })?;

    let status = child.wait()?;
    let runtime = start.elapsed();

    Ok(Invocation {
        stdout,
        stderr,
        // TODO handle signals, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66272686
        exit_code: status.code().unwrap_or(126),
        runtime,
    })
}
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on the implementation - or especially the API - of this function<sup>1</sup>. In particular:

- Callers are expected to provide a pair of `impl Write+Send` types, which is compatible with `std::io::Stdout`/`Stderr` as well as user-provided types such as `&mut Vec<u8>` (specifically intended for unit testing).

  - Unfortunately `StdoutLock`/`StderrLock` are not `Send` and therefore cannot be specified here - in principle I believe that would be a better option but I'm not sure how to support that along with other `Write` impls.
- `std::thread::scope` is used to simplify the sinks' signature - without scoping I believe it's necessary to use `impl Write+Send+'static` which prevents using borrowed types like `&mut Vec<u8>`.
- Trying to avoid `.expect()` but I'm not sure how to do so with the `.join()` results, when I swap the expect for `?` I hit errors.
- Any general feedback about idiomatic Rust and patterns that could be improved / simplified here.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course if you're interested in taking a look at the whole PR that'd be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Some thoughts that occurred to me: 1) The function is too long, i.e. it has a too large cognitive complexity for my taste. 2) No docstrings (triple `///`) that describe the function, its params and return value. 3) You introduce threading, but `.take()` the output streams.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I agree it's long, but I felt pulling the `maybe_tee()` helper out would just pollute the class' namespace. Maybe it's worth doing anyways though. What's the issue with using `.take()` here? I borrowed that pattern from the linked SO post.

Comment: Sorry. I jumped th gun there. I was under the impression, that you were locking `stdout` in a thread, which is not actually the case.